# How to intercept exception in Future in scalatest?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, scalatest

I am trying to intercept exception in my test(with exception message).

My test code:

```
class Test4 extends WordSpec with Matchers with ScalaFutures with ScalatestRouteTest {

"should fail if no valid" should {
  "should throw ex if name is not valid" in {
    whenReady(userService.createUser(wrongNameRequest)) {
      _ shouldBe UserCreateException("incorrect name")
    }
  }
}
```

But it looks like scalatest don't react properly on my "should". It behaves itself as no interception exists.(I am sure in this: _ shouldBe UserCreateException("incorrect name"))

So in tests results, I have got this:

```
  - should should throw ex if a name is not valid *** FAILED ***
[info]     The future returned an exception of type: userapi.model.UserCreateException, with the message:  incorrect name.
```

Comment: I am not sure what is that `whenReady` but as you can see in the [**docs**](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async testing) that you can use `recoverToExceptionIf[UserCreateException] { FUTUREBLOCK }`

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I should use fullname -

```
_ shouldBe userapi.model.UserCreateException(" incorrect name")
```